# yarn creating seemingly unnecessary dependencies

Tags: javascript, dependency-management, yarnpkg, semantic-versioning, npm-package

I've published a private package to a URL as a tarball and am consuming it in another package, but when I install it it is installing things it shouldn't (in my opinion).

My private package's `package.json` looks like this in dependencies:

```
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
```

The package that is consuming it looks like this:

```
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3"
```

Yet when my private package is installed with yarn it creates its own `node_modules` folder and installs rxjs and lodash, despite the package it is installed in already having packages that, to my understanding, fulfill its requirements.

1. Am I not declaring the dependencies correctly in my private
   package (or the package that consumes it?)
2. Does this have something to do with the nature of the private
   package - it's just a tarball containing a build folder and a `package.json`?

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen. If you expect this package to be installed in projects that already declare those dependencies, make them `peerDependencies`.